# How can I show forms one after another in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to ask one question at a time like "How much did you score in X", when a user selects any of the given buttons, next question will be displayed, this will continue to a certain limit say 10.

[image: angular]

Currently I'm displaying all those questions through a loop ng-repeat.

```
<div ng-repeat="subcode in subjects">
<label class="control-label" for="radios">How much did you score in SUBJECT {{subcode}}?</label>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-m">
<button ng-repeat="grade in gradebuttons" ng-click="saveclick(subcode,grade)" type="button" class="btn btn-default">{{grade}}</button>
</div>
<br/>
</div>
<button ng-click="calculate()">Calculate</button>
```

my calculate function uses the subcode,grade from saveclick function to process them and display the result just beneath the button.

Also I'm not sure how do I allow user to select just one button, like if they select A1 and again selects A2 in the same subject, previous A1 should be replaced. At this time all grades are selected from all subjects.

Comment: do you want to turn back previous questions?

Comment: No, i don't want to. If they're answered or clicked, let them be hidden forever unless a new button "Start Again" is clicked, which will clear up everything.

Comment: I already did the "start again" button part, now I just need to know how can I show those forms one after another?

Comment: ok let me do a plunker for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-show` to show current step by using `$index` and create a variable like `currentStep`

```
<div ng-repeat="subcode in subjects" ng-show="currentStep == $index">
```

which shows only the current question in the list while hiding others

You should update `currentStep` everytime you save a click to jump up to next question...

```
$scope.saveclick = function (subcode,grade) {
    $scope.answers.push({'subcode' : subcode, 'grade' : grade});
    $scope.currentStep++;
}
```

here is my [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/72IxJZ?p=preview)

Comment: @user2714639 You are welcome if you need further help just add another comment...

Answer (score 1):

try something like

```
<div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]" ng-click="increment(j)" ng-show="$index+1 == j">
    <div >{{$index}} How much did you score in SUBJECT {{i}}</div>
</div>`
```

`increment` is the scope method which increments the index.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="subcode in subjects">
    <label class="control-label" for="radios">How much did you score in SUBJECT {{subcode}}?</label>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-m">
      <button ng-repeat="grade in gradebuttons" ng-click="saveclick(subcode,grade)"
      type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-show="selectedGrades[subjects[$parent.$index-1]] || $parent.$index== 0" ng-class="{selected: selectedGrades[subcode] == grade}" >{{grade}}</button>
    </div>
    <br/>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="calculate()">Calculate</button>
```

Your JS code:

```
$scope.saveclick = function (subcode,grade){
    $scope.selectedGrades[subcode] = grade; //replace previous selected grade.
  };

  $scope.selectedGrades = {};
```

Try:

- `ng-show="selectedGrades[subjects[$parent.$index-1]] || $parent.$index== 0"` to show 1 question at a time and show next when the previous question has been answered.
- `ng-class="{selected: selectedGrades[subcode] == grade}"` to highlight the current selected grade for the subject.

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/lSm97F0NoY4dzkNvCuW0?p=preview)

If you need to hide the entire question instead of just buttons, move the `ng-show` to the question and change it to `ng-show="selectedGrades[subjects[$index-1]] || $index== 0"`

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/MSkpsyrDpQqVcu9HcIAJ?p=preview)

If you need to hide the question as soon as it's answer, try: `ng-show="(selectedGrades[subjects[$index-1]] || $index== 0) && !selectedGrades[subcode]"`

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/igGTqeD3WGJK4ZCflAIW?p=preview)

Comment: please let me know if I understand your requirement correctly.

Comment: you were spot on friend, but I'm still figuring out how did you do the magic lol. Actually I also wanted to the hide the question as soon as it is answered so that the next question takes it's place. I started working on angularjs just today only, sorry for being a noob.

Comment: @user2714639: See my updated answer with 1 more demo